# join 2 tables that have no foreign key to eact other

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```py
class A(Base):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    ...

class B(Base):
    head_number = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    ...
```

there is 2 model that have no relation to each other, how its possible to write query below with annotate in django orm?

```
Select * from A
inner join B on A.number = B.head_number
```

I had tried with `extra()` and it works, but I want to have it with `annotate()`.
and it can not change any model .
Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter using [**`in`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) field lookup.

```
A.objects.filter(number__in=B.objects.values_list('head_number', flat=True))
```

This queryset **`B.objects.values_list(..)`** will be evaluated as subselect statement(subquery in where clause)